# Fast rising memory when starting webworker in node.js with "big" data

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, web-worker

I have the typical code to start a webworker in node:

```
var Threads = require('webworker-threads');    
var worker = new Threads.Worker(__dirname + '/workers/myworker.js');

worker.onmessage = function (event) {
    // 1.
    // ... create and execute cypher query ...
};

// Start the worker.
worker.postMessage({
    'data' : data
});
```

At 1. I send small pieces of processed data to a Neo4J db.
For small `data` this works perfectly fine, but when the data gets slightly bigger node/the worker starts to struggle.

The actual `data` I want to process is a csv I parsed with BabyParse resulting in an object with 149000 properties where each has another 17 properties. (149000 rows by 17 columns = 2533000 properties). The file is 17MB.

When doing this node will allocate a lot of memory and eventually crash around 53% memory allocation. The machine has 4GB.

The worker looks roughly like this:

```
self.onmessage = function (event) {
    process(event.data.data);
};

function process(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        self.postMessage({
            'properties' : data[i]
        });
    }
}
```

I tried to chunk the data and process it chunkwise within the worker which also works okay. But I want to generate a graph and to process the edges I need the complete data, because I need to check every row (vertex) against all others.

Is there a way to stream the data into the worker? Or does anyone have an idea why node allocates so much memory with 17MB of data being send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of parsing the data in the main thread you can also pass the filename as a message to the worker and have the worker load it from disk. Otherwise you will have all the data in memory twice, once in the host and once in the worker.

A different option would be to use the [csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv) npm package with the streaming parser. `postMessage` the lines as they come in and buffer them up till the final result in the worker.

Why your solution tries to allocate those enormous amounts of memory I don't know. I do know `postMessage` is intended to pass small messages.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that the filesystem is available in web workers.